# Turbogears. Writing controller methods

Tags: controller, turbogears

The `index` method is the start point of any TurboGears controller class. Each of the URLs

- `localhost:8080`
- `localhost:8080/`
- `localhost:8080/index`

is mapped to the `RootController.index()` method.

How can I map `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/` to the `.index()`  but `localhost:8080/index` and `localhost:8080/index.html` to the `._lookup()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Don't place any index method inside your controller and just use _lookup returning the right controller depending on what you want to do.

This will return 'INDEX1' for *http://localhost:8080* and *http://localhost:8080/* while returning 'INDEX2' for *http://localhost:8080/index* and *http://localhost:8080/index.html*

```python
class IndexController(BaseController):
    @expose()
    def index(self, *args, **kw):
        return 'INDEX2'

class NoPathController(BaseController):
    @expose()
    def index(self, *args, **kw):
        return 'INDEX1'

class RootController(BaseController):
    @expose()
    def _lookup(self, *remainder, **params):
        if not remainder:
            return NoPathController(), remainder

        return IndexController(), remainder
```